# Operations for polyhedral point groups

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, geometric-group-theory

I am developing a library for geometric symmetry groups. The [international tables of crystallography](http://it.iucr.org/Ac/contents/) list the complete operator list for wallpaper groups and space groups, but I've been unable to locate such a list for 3D point groups. I've derived the seven axial groups myself [here](https://github.com/sbliven/symmetrycad/blob/master/SymmetryCAD/point_groups.scad), but I haven't figured out the seven polygonal point groups yet. Does anyone have a list of all operators for $T$, $T_h$, $T_d$, $O$, $O_h$, $I$, and $I_h$? I would also prefer to follow existing conventions for the axes choices, if these have been standardized anywhere.

Expressing the operations in $(x,y,z)$ form is fine, although I will eventually need to translate that into 4D rotation matrix form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find any pre-existing operator list for 3D point groups, nor any standard for the choice of axis or order of operators. As such I ended up deriving the operators from their generators. The [OpenSCAD code](https://github.com/sbliven/symmetrycad/blob/master/SymmetryCAD/point_groups.scad) for the results should be easy to port to other languages if needed. Here's a summary:

### Chiral tetrahedral ($T$)

Orientation: Given a cube oriented to the cartesian axes, we have 2-fold rotation axes through each face (i.e. along the axes) and 3-fold axes through each body diagonal.

Generators: 2-fold around X ($R_2$); 3-fold around (1,1,1) ($R_3$)

$$
R_2 =   \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0&-1& 0& 0\\
0& 0&-1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
R_3 =    \begin{pmatrix}
0& 0& 1& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operators (12):

$$
T = \{e,
R_2, R_3,
R_2 R_3, R_3 R_2, R_3 R_3,
R_2 R_3 R_3, R_2 R_3 R_2, R_3 R_2 R_3, R_3 R_3 R_2,
R_3 R_3 R_2 R_3, R_3 R_2 R_3 R_3 \}
$$

### Full tetrahedral ($T_d$)

Orientation: Same as $T$, with 6 additional mirror planes containing opposing edges of the cube.

Generators: Same as $T$, plus a reflection across x=y ($M_{x=y}$)

$$
M_{x=y} = \begin{pmatrix}
0& 1& 0& 0\\
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operators (24):

All operators in $T$ plus mirrored versions
$$
T_d = T \cup \left\{r\cdot M_{x=y}:r\in T\right\}
$$

### Pyritohedral ($T_h$)

Orientation: Same as $T$, with 6 additional mirror planes containing opposing edges of the cube.

Generators: Same as $T$, plus a reflection across xz ($M_{xz}$)
$$
M_{xz} = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0&-1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operators (24):

All operators in $T$ plus mirrored versions
$$
T_h = T \cup \left\{r\cdot M_{xz}:r\in T\right\}
$$

### Chiral Octohedral ($O$)

Orientation: Given a cube oriented to the cartesian axes, we have 4-fold rotation axes through each face (i.e. along the axes), 3-fold axes through each body diagonal, and 2-fold rotations through the edge midpoints

Generators: 4-fold around X ($R_4$); 3-fold around (1,1,1) ($R_3$)
$$
R_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0&-1& 0\\
0& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operators (24):

$$
O = \{e,
R_3, R_4,
R_3 R_3, R_3 R_4, R_4 R_3, R_4 R_4,
R_3 R_3 R_4, R_3 R_4 R_4, R_4 R_3 R_3, R_4 R_4 R_3, R_4 R_4 R_4,
R_3 R_3 R_4 R_4, R_3 R_4 R_3 R_3, R_3 R_4 R_4 R_3, R_3 R_4 R_4 R_4, R_4 R_3 R_3 R_4, R_4 R_4 R_3 R_3,
R_3 R_3 R_4 R_3 R_3, R_3 R_3 R_4 R_4 R_3, R_4 R_4 R_3 R_3 R_4, R_3 R_4 R_4 R_3 R_3, R_4 R_3 R_3 R_4 R_4,
R_3 R_4 R_4 R_3 R_3 R_4\}
$$

### Full octohedral ($O_h$)

Orientation: Same as $O$, with additional mirror planes along the axes and containing opposing edges of the cube.

Generators: Same as $O$, plus a reflection across xz ($M_{xz}$)

Operators (48):

All operators in $O$ plus mirrored versions
$$
O_h = O \cup \left\{r\cdot M_{xz}:r\in O\right\}
$$

### Chiral icosahedral ($I$)

Orientation: Orient an icosahedron such that each axis is along a 2-fold axis.

Generators: 2-fold around X ($R_2$), plus a 5-fold rotation around the $(\phi,0,1)$ axis ($R_5$).

$$
f = \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{5+\sqrt{5}} \\
g = \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{4} \\
\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \\
R_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{f}{2}&         -\frac{\phi \sqrt{f}}{2}& \frac{\phi f}{2}&   0\\
\frac{\phi \sqrt{f}}{2}& 1-f (\frac{1}{2}+g)&    -g \sqrt{f}&0\\
\frac{\phi f}{2}&       g \sqrt{f}&      1-f g&     0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Operators (60):

Use the decomposition $I = T\times C_5$:

$$
I = \left\{R_5^i \cdot r:r\in T, i \in [0\ldots4] \right\}
$$

### Full icosahedral ($I_h$)

Orientation: Same as $I$, with mirror planes

Generators: Same as $I$, plus XZ reflection ($M_{xz}$)

Operators (120):

$$
I_h = I \cup \left\{r \cdot M_{xz}:r\in I \right\}
$$